# Shiny: Reactive slider produces error in plot: "invalid 'xlim' value"

Tags: r, shiny

I want to produce a reactive slider with `shiny`. However, I guess as the plot is produced before the reactive input is evaluated, an error appers for a short moment.
When I use `ggplot` instead of `plot` the error is: `Asthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data`

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel(""),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("check", "scale 0 to 30", F),
      
      # here is the reactive slider
      uiOutput("slider")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plt")
    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$slider <- renderUI({
      sliderInput("inSlider", "Reactive scale", 
                  min   = ifelse(input$check == T,  0, 0), 
                  max   = ifelse(input$check == T, 30, 100), 
                  value = ifelse(input$check == T, 20, 20))
  })
    
    output$plt <- renderPlot({
      
      plot(mtcars$qsec, mtcars$mpg, xlim=c(0,input$inSlider))
      
    })

})
```

[image]

So my question is: How can I avoid this error?

Comment: that is, because `input$inSlider` is NULL initially. You should wrap the plot in `if(!is.null(input$inSlider)){...}`. However, i am pretty sure the question was already asked in a similar way, pls check for duplicates,...

Comment: actually I think adding `req(input$inSlider)` as the first line of `output$plot` would be the right thing to do. It was created for exactly this scenario. JC has even apologized often for not creating it in an earlier iteration of shiny than he did. As a joke of course :) - since Shiny is practically perfect in every way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `req(input$inSlider)` as the first line of `output$plot`.

That construct was created about a year and a half ago for exactly this scenario.

It was supposed to cut down on the number of `if(!is.null(input$..` that were plaguing Shiny and making programs unreadable. Unfortunately most simple examples you find on SO or the net do not have that construct - or even the `if(!is.null..` form. So this keeps reoccurring, with different symptoms.